# sockeye install version 2.2.7

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a model trained with sockeye version 2.2.7. The major code version has to match.[1,2] So I'm trying to install 2.2.7. There is no tag for 2.2.7 in https://github.com/awslabs/sockeye/tags and https://pypi.org/project/sockeye/#history. Is there a way to install 2.2.7?

[1] https://github.com/awslabs/sockeye/issues/793

[2] https://github.com/awslabs/sockeye/issues/916

Answer (score 0, accepted):

version 2.2.8 runs a model trained on 2.2.7 [1]

Installing 2.2.8:

```
pip install sockeye==2.2.8
```

[1] https://github.com/awslabs/sockeye/issues/927